# How to make localhost to send email?

Tags: php, email, xampp, localhost

I am unable to send mails through localhost Xampp even after making changes in php.ini and sedmail.php files as per [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost).
 I have adoubt in sendmail.php file what email & PassWord to give here;

```
auth_username=   
auth_password=
```

Please somebody get me through this.

Comment: its your email username and password

Comment: Are you using gmail username?

Comment: What is error message?

Comment: @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd, I get an error message as "You have disabled email sending"

Comment: @ roullie, I gave my gmail ID & PW, But still no luck favored !

Answer (score 0):

Let we resolve this issue by follow some steps.

**1. Make sure error reporting is enabled and set to report all errors(use code in .php file)**

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
set_error_handler("var_dump");
```

**2. Check your server's mail logs**

Your *localhost* should be logging all attempts to send emails through it. The location of these logs will user's root directory under logs. Inside will be error messages the server reported, if any, related to your attempts to send emails.

**3. Make sure you have a mail server set up on localhost**

If you are developing on your local workstation using *XAMPP*, an email server is probably not installed on your workstation. Without one, *PHP* cannot send mail by default.

You can overcome this by installing a basic mail server. For Windows you can use the [free Mercury Mail](http://www.pmail.com/overviews/ovw_mercury.htm).

You can also use *SMTP* to send your emails. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18185233/250259) to re-check how to do this.

**4. Check to see if mail() returns true or false with message**

Please use below code and let me know what happen. This code will display actual error message and we can resolve this issue.

*Replace*

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

*With*

```
$mailReturn = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
print('<pre>');
print_r($mailReturn);
print('</pre>');
exit();
```

If above 3 steps done perfect but no success then follow step 4. Let me know what this code print.

**5. SMTP settings(in php.ini) for send mail from localhost**

If you are using *Gmail* then you got lucky. *Gmail* lets us use their *SMTP* provided that you will have to authenticate it using your own **username** and **password**. To use *Gmail SMTP* the values will be like below:

```
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

//enable this if you are using gmail smtp, for mandrill app it is not required
//$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

//Set the SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
$mail->Port = 25;
//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Username to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "YOUR.ID@GMAIL.COM";
//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "YOUR_PASSWORD";
```

Or, if you don't want to use your *Gmail* account then I would suggest to create one account on [Mandrill](https://mandrill.com) and get your *SMTP* host, *username* and *password* from there. I have tested both gmail and mandrill and they are working pretty good.

```
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = "smtp.mandrillapp.com";
//Set the SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
$mail->Port = 25;
//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Username to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "YOUR_REGISTER_EMAIL@MANDRILL.COM";
//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "YOUR_PASSWORD";
```

Make sure all variables value are checked and change if require.

Comment: when I add step 1 & step 2 snippets to php.ini file, it is throwing error as syntax error.

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: syntax error, unexpecte '('in C:\xampp\php\php.ini on line 1832

Comment: and what is the code at 1832 line?

Comment: Sorry, use step 1 code into .php file not in .ini file. you can use that code before mail() function calling.

Comment: Which .php file please

Comment: sedmail.php, use code before mail() calling. The best approach is use at first line.

Comment: Im getting this error 'The e-mail could not be sent.
Possible reason: your host may have disabled the mail() function.'

Comment: You are using gmail account?

Comment: Please check 5 point, I updated my answer.

Comment: I already did these settings prior to your answer, don't know were is the fault

Comment: Final way is you need to use phpmailer mail helper for mail send functionality.

Comment: OK Thanks, let me check with this, hope this turns out into flying color

Comment: You can find this library with example here: https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer

Comment: Your issue is resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SMTP mail sending library and try that function to send the mail from localhost